# How to sort list of elements look like (cell(I,J) = Value) by the Indexes?

Tags: prolog

For example, the input is the list

```
[ cell(3,5) = 1, cell(7,6) = 2, cell(5,4) = 6, cell(9,7) = 8 ]
```

and the output is the list

```
[ cell(3,5) = 1, cell(5,4) = 6, cell(7,6) = 2, cell(9,7) = 8 ]
```

Comment: In swi-prolog, can use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/4

Answer (score 1):

Use ISO built-in predicate [sort/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2):

```
?- L=[cell(3, 5)=1, cell(7, 6)=2, cell(5, 4)=6, cell(3, 4)=2,cell(9, 7)=8], sort(L,S).
L = [cell(3, 5)=1, cell(7, 6)=2, cell(5, 4)=6, cell(3, 4)=2, cell(9, 7)=8],
S = [cell(3, 4)=2, cell(3, 5)=1, cell(5, 4)=6, cell(7, 6)=2, cell(9, 7)=8].
```

Comment: @brebs Why not?!?

Comment: @brebs Have you observed that I've altered the example to check another property of the proposed solution?  Predicate `sort(L,S)` succeeds if `S` can be unified with a list holding the elements of `L`, sorted to the **standard order of terms**. Since the items of the list are terms of the form `cell(I,J)=V`, naturally, they will be sorted first by index `I`, then by index `J` and, finally, by value `V`.

Comment: Ah, you added an element to L. OK.